# Difference between “tard” and “retard”

Tags: grammaire, sens, vocabulaire

As far as I know, both words mean the same — “late”. Is there any difference in their meaning? And also how are they used in a sentence?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

"Tard" is an adverb, while "retard" is a noun. "Retard" actually means "lateness" or "delay". Some examples:

> - It is late: *Il est tard*
> - Please forgive us for this delay: *Veuillez nous excuser pour ce retard*
> - To arrive late: *Arriver en retard* (arrive with some delay) or *Arriver tard* (arrive late in the evening, for example)